# Calculating the height of the content

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I bring out several blocks of text, information for which is taken from the json document.

Next, I calculate the height of these blocks, which would specify the height of the cell in UICollectionview.
Here is the code:

```
if(indexPath.item == 0){
        var heightContent: CGFloat = 0
        for number in contentArray{
            if(number.switcher == 1){
                let approximateWidthOfTitlePost = view.frame.width - 15 - 15 - 25
                let sizeTitle = CGSize(width: approximateWidthOfTitlePost, height: 2000)
                let attributeTitle = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)]
                let estimatedFrameText = NSString(string: number.content!).boundingRect(with: sizeTitle, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: attributeTitle, context: nil)
                heightContent += estimatedFrameText.height + 20
            }
            if(number.switcher == 2){
                heightContent += 250 + 20
            }
            if(number.switcher == 3){
                let approximateWidthOfFirstCaption = view.frame.width - 15 - 15 - 10
                let sizeFirstCaption = CGSize(width: approximateWidthOfFirstCaption, height: 2000)
                let attributeFirstCaption = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: UIFont.Weight.semibold)]
                let estimatedFrameText = NSString(string: number.content!).boundingRect(with: sizeFirstCaption, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: attributeFirstCaption, context: nil)
                heightContent += estimatedFrameText.height
            }
        }
        let approximateWidthOfTitlePost = view.frame.width - 15 - 15 - 10
        let sizeTitle = CGSize(width: approximateWidthOfTitlePost, height: 2000)
        let attributeTitle = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 24, weight: UIFont.Weight.semibold)]
        let estimatedFrameTitle = NSString(string: (postInfo?.titlePost)!).boundingRect(with: sizeTitle, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: attributeTitle, context: nil)

        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: heightContent + 15 + 30  + 13 + estimatedFrameTitle.height + 15)
```

The problem is that the calculated height has a wide range of values. And as a result, there is a big difference when displaying a cell on the screen:
[First](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWGQt.png)
[Second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTOKd.png)

anchor of this kind: `image.anchor(bottomAnchor, left: self.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: self.rightAnchor, topConstant: 15, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 250)`

Question: How to calculate the height more accurately?

Sorry for my english

Comment: Use auto-layout instead  of *calculating* the label heights.

Comment: @DonMag How to find the bottom cell anchor? I'm not working with a storyboard. The entire layout was carried out by code

Comment: You don't need Storyboard to use auto-layout. Are you using a collection view to display only a single "column" of cells? If yes, You may find it (much) easier to use a tableView.

Comment: @DonMag I did not immediately understand what you mean, but trying different variants with UITableView, I realized what you mean. Your method really worked for me. Thank you very much!!!!! I regret that I did not ask the question before.